# Mysql Order By count?

Tags: mysql

Actually I'm working with the following table **fsa_areas**:
[image: fsa_areas]

> Note that each area has a responsible

Now, what I need to do, is to order the same table as following:
[image: Required table]

> Note that now the results are ordered by the the responsible with more areas and at the end the responsible with less areas.

**Is there a way to order them in that way?**

Comment: Could you make this question any more confusing?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your sample data is confusing, because it looks like you just need to `ORDER BY Responsible`, while you probably want to group by the count.

Comment: just I need to order the results according to the value 'responsible', in this case 4 is on the top because is the the most repeated(is repeated 3 time) value, then 57(repeated 2 times) and the end 58 which only appears one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a COUNT subquery in the ORDER BY clause:

```
select a.*
from fsa_areas a
order by (select count(*) from fsa_areas a1 where a1.Responsible = a.Responsible) desc
```

Another way is to get the count in a derived table and join the base table to it

```
select a.*
from (
  select Responsible, count(*) as cnt
  from fsa_areas
  group by Responsible
) r
join fsa_areas a using(Responsible)
order by r.cnt desc
```

In MySQL 8 you can use COUNT() as window function:

```
select *, count(*) over (partition by Responsible) as cnt
from fsa_areas
order by cnt desc
```